# How to refresh the table records automatically in angularjs after an event occurs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

I am working on a Web App  , using Laravel as backend API and AngularJS for frontend. I have successfully fetched the data from Laravel API and displayed it via AngularJS ng-repeat . Now i want a delete button for each record which is displayed in the table.When a user click that delete button it should delete the clicked record.I did the following try which is working perfectly.But the problem occurs when i click delete button it deletes record from database but it is not refreshing the records list , instead of refreshing it just shows the headers titles of table and nothing else. When i manually refresh it from browser then it displays back the records list.I want to load the list automatically after the record is deleted.

***Summary***: On delete i want to load / refresh the list automatically which is not happening right now.

**Student Controller:**

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $student = Student::find(Input::get('id'));
        if($student){
            $student->delete();
            return Response::json(['destroy'=>true]);
        }
    }
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['mainCtrl', 'myAppService']);
```

**myappservice.js**

```
angular.module('myAppService', [])

    .factory('Result', function($http) {
        return {
            get : function() {
                return $http.get('api/result');
            },
            show : function(id) {
                return $http.get('api/result/' + id);
            },
            save : function(resultData) {
                return $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'api/result',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                    data: $.param(resultData)
                });
            },
            destroy : function(id) {
                return $http.delete('api/result/' + id,{params: {id}});
            }
        }

    });
```

**MainCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('mainCtrl', [])

    .controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, Result) {
        // object to hold all the data for the new comment form
        $scope.resultData = {};

        // loading variable to show the spinning loading icon
        $scope.loading = true;

        // get all the comments first and bind it to the $scope.comments object
        Result.get()
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.students = data;
                $scope.loading = false;
            });


        // function to handle submitting the form
        $scope.submitResult = function() {
            $scope.loading = true;

            // save the comment. pass in comment data from the form
            Result.save($scope.resultData)
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.resultData = {};
                    // if successful, we'll need to refresh the comment list
                    Result.get()
                        .success(function(getData) {
                            $scope.students = getData;
                            $scope.loading = false;
                        });

                })
                .error(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
        };

        // function to handle deleting a comment
        $scope.deleteResult = function(id) {
            $scope.loading = true; 

            Result.destroy(id)
                .success(function(data) {

                    // if successful, we'll need to refresh the comment list
                    Result.get()
                        .success(function(getData) {
                            $scope.students = getData;
                            $scope.loading = false;
                        });

                });
        };

    });
```

**View**

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th>Roll No</th>
                                <th>Student Name</th>
                                <th>Father Name</th>
                                <th>Obtained Marks</th>
                                <th>Total Marks</th>
                                <th>Percentage</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody ng-hide="loading" ng-repeat="student in students | filter:searchText">
                                  <tr> 
                                    <td>@{{ student.rollno }}</td>
                                    <td>@{{ student.name }}</td>
                                    <td>@{{ student.fname }}</td>
                                    <td>@{{ student.obtainedmarks }}</td>
                                    <td>@{{ student.totalmarks }}</td>
                                    <td>@{{ student.percentage }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#" ng-click="deleteResult(student.id)" class="text-muted btn-danger btn-lg">Delete</a></p>
                                    </td>

                                  </tr>
                            </tbody>
</table>
```

> Console Error: DELETE
>   http://localhost/ngresulty/public/api/result/30?id=30 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

Comment: have you checked console error and response data when you delete row?

Comment: in console i get `DELETE http://localhost/ngresulty/public/api/result/30?id=30 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: if you get 500 interval server error which means your success functio doesnt called, it calls error fuction, fix problem at server side

Comment: But when i refresh the list./records manually the record is deleted . Means success.What you say ? I just want the list to refreshed automatically after the deletion is occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that the `Result.get()` call is not returning the right data. You may want to check that endpoint.

Instead of making another call though, since you know that on deletion there was a success event, you could just change the scope then and not call your backend again, ie:

```
    // function to handle deleting a comment
    $scope.deleteResult = function(id) {
        $scope.loading = true; 

        Result.destroy(id)
            .success(function(data) {

                // do something with data if you want to
                $scope.students.splice(id, 1);

            });
    };
```

Comment: still same problem

Answer (score 0):

if you get 500 server error `Result.destroy()` calls error function. Its not success

```
    $scope.loading = true; 

            Result.destroy(id)
                .success(function(data) {
                    // if successful, we'll need to refresh the comment list
                    Result.get()
                        .success(function(getData) {
                            $scope.students = getData;
                            $scope.loading = false;
                        });

                })
                .error(function(data) {
                    // its not successful but i want call Result.get() anyway
                    Result.get()
                        .success(function(getData) {
                            $scope.students = getData;
                            $scope.loading = false;
                        });

                }));
        };
```

Comment: Still same problem not refreshing the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put 
$scope.$apply();
statement at the end of event

Comment: still same problem . Delete occurs but list is not refreshing automatically